# Flex-box sizing to children

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I have an angular webpage using Angular Material and Flex-box. This page will have a graph that retains its ratio and therefore has a max-width set to prevent it from taking up too much vertical space. I want to set the parent div of the graph to only take up as much horizontal space as the child element. I will fill the rest of the horizontal space with a div that has fxLayout column and will stretch vertically.

Currently

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
        <app-graph></app-graph> //max-width: 1300px
        <app-results></app-results>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="30" style="background-color: red;">

    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

I am getting closer. I found setting the fxFlex="0 1 1300px" gives me the behavior I want of the first div. I can't figure out what to do for the 2nd div so that it continues to fill the remaining space.

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 1 1300px">
        <app-graph></app-graph>
        <app-results></app-results>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="20" style="background-color: red;">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `flex-grow` to automatic adapt this.

Comment: just add flex-grow 1 to the last column in the row and it will automatically make the first column the size of it's content and then make the second column fill the remaining space (if the parent row is flex)

Comment: I've tried this. It only squishes the graph all the way to the left.

Comment: Ok. Using flex-gow (in angular case, fxFlex-"grow"), get's me about half of what i want to accomplish. It locks the left div to the minimum width of the <app-results> component. Now, if Increase the view area, the right div continues to fill, but the left div stays the same. My goal is to have the left div flexible until it hits the maximum width of the child components and the right div have the ability to grow. I may need to rethink my layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with to get what I wanted. Still not perfect, but it retains the min and max size of the first component.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayout="start stretch">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 1 1100px" style="margin: 0 5px;">
        <app-graph></app-graph>
        <app-results></app-results>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex style="border: black solid 1px; margin: 0 5px;">
        <p style="font-size: 4em">Stuff will go here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```